# GAS custom function return next activity in sequence

Tags: arrays, function, google-apps-script

I'm attempting to return alternative activities into the white cells in the linked spreadsheet. The sequence of actions are as follows:

1. Place the custom function in the **Calendar table** row & identify the
   adjacent *Workout Type*.
2. Return the name of the **next** activity from the *Alternate Activities* based on the *Workout Type*
3. If the matching activity is the last of the *Workout Type*, start over again.

Ideally, the spreadsheet should be as the image below:
[image]

Instead, it's returning the result as shown below in [the linked spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16li86UxKwDl4LUzgEdpfWdbZuDYcZ0t-adNJN56-bzQ/edit?pli=1#gid=0);
[image]

The logic of the function carrying out the work is:

```
/**
*@customfunction
*@NotOnlyCurrentDoc
*/
function altNxt(parameterRowNumber, parameterColNumber) 
{
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var startRow = 3; //define start row - Far too static. Any change in sheet makes the function fail
  var startCol = 2; //define start col - Far too static. Any change in sheet makes the function fail
  var endRow = parameterRowNumber; 
  
  var numRows = (endRow - startRow) + 1;
  var numColumns = 7; 
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet().getRange(startRow, startCol, numRows, numColumns);
  var largeArray = sheet.getValues();  
  
  var arrayColPosition = parameterColNumber - startCol;
  var arrayRowPosition = parameterRowNumber - startRow; 
  var trigger = false;

  var finalArray = largeArray.map((r, i) => i == arrayRowPosition ? r.map((y, c) => c == arrayColPosition ? y[arrayColPosition] = '*' : y) : r);
  
  var calendar_array = finalArray.map((r, indexRow) => r.map((c, indexColumn) => {
    if(c == '*') trigger = true;
      if(indexColumn >= arrayColPosition && trigger || indexRow > arrayRowPosition ){
        return '';
      }else{
        return c;
      }
  }));

  var sheet2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet().getRange(25, 1, 21, 2);
  var alternative_activities = sheet2.getValues();
  
  //This is to set the cell position relative to the ARRAY, not the spreadsheet
  var arrayRowPosition = parameterRowNumber - startRow; 
  var arrayColPosition = parameterColNumber - startCol;

  for (row = calendar_array.length - 1; row >= 0; row--)
  {
    for (column = calendar_array[0].length - 1; column >= 0; column--)
    {
      for (row2 = 0; row2 <= alternative_activities.length; row2++)
      {
        for (column2 = alternative_activities[0].length - 1; column2 >= 0; column2--)
        {
          if (calendar_array[row][column] != "")
          {
           if (calendar_array[row][column] == alternative_activities[row2][column2] && calendar_array[row][0] == alternative_activities[row2][0])
           {
             return alternative_activities[row2+1][1];
           }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Any help would be great on this. Thanks!!!

Comment: If I understood your question correctly, it is supposed to disribute the alternate activitites to the white cells according to the Workout type?

Answer (score 0):

Error was due to the itteration through the 2nd array. The limit was set to high.